# Unable to Set Size (Increase Size) for Chrome Browser through Selenium in Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am not able to increase chrome window size through selenium in jenkins , maximum it is increasing to 1036, 780,

i tried with reducing the browser size then it is working but it is not increasing the size, it works fine for firefox driver ,

facing problem only with chrome driver not with firefox

i tried with below logics:-

System.setProperty(Chrome_driver_initiation,chrome_driver_path);

driver = new ChromeDriver();

1. driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1900, 1000));
2. driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
       driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1900, 1000));
3. ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
       driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
4. driver.manage().window().maximize();
5. Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
         int width =(int) toolkit.getScreenSize().getWidth();
         int height = (int)toolkit.getScreenSize().getHeight();
         driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
6. ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("window-size=1936,1056");
       driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
7. ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.resizeTo(1936, 1056)");

above logic's are working fine in local-System but not in jenkins slave, please anyone help on this.

Comment: Hello @Sumanth Urs, have you found solution for the OP.If yes please let me know.I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Chrome disallows setting the size larger than the system's screen resolution width, the problem may be this in your case. Some workaround could be to maximize the window to at least have the largest window available on that system.

Comment: This was the problem to me. On my local box, the '--window-size=800,600' was working fine. But, on TeamCity, which runs on a VM no. The screenshots all came in the same resolution. Just to test out, I put the window size to 400,400 and I could see the screenshot smaller. Somehow need now to adjust the VM resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The only method worked for me was to reduce the font size for the contents displayed in screen, otherwise when Jenkins as service when launches chrome driver don't let you maximize or resize. the alternative was to reduce the font size so all of it can fit even if it's not maximized.

`//reduce font size
options.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.50");
options.addArguments("high-dpi-support=0.50");`

**Like shown below**

```
`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path-to\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-web-security --disable-extensions --            disable-extensions-file-access-check --disable-extensions-http-throttling --disable-infobars --enable-automation");
//reduce font size
options.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.50");
options.addArguments("high-dpi-support=0.50");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled",false);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
new DesiredCapabilities();
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run your test in jenkins in headless mode and in that way you will be able to set the size you want it for

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the font size worked.
Adding `headless` option with Chrome seems to be working for me:

```
option.addArguments("--headless")
```

Comment: +1 for headless. Nothing seemed to work for me except this. I believe Jenkins is unable to resize the browser well to perform the required task.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--window-size=1280,1024");
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, only passing param to build command works for me.

```
mvn clean install Dselenide.browserSize=1900x1200
```

Comment: -Dselenide.browserSize.

Of course, only if Selenide is in use.