# Unable to Maximize browser when running through Jenkins as windows service

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

When running test script through windows , am unable to maximize the browser window due to which the scripts are getting failed ,

tried all possible ways as mentioned in this thread , but no use 
[Unable to Set Size (Increase Size) for Chrome Browser through Selenium in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605484/unable-to-set-size-increase-size-for-chrome-browser-through-selenium-in-jenkin)

Is there way to maximize the window ?? any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you control the "slaves"? You can interact with desktop if the slave is launched as normal program.

Comment: No i don't have any slaves , Jenkins runs on my local host 8080 server.

Comment: I too had the similar problem, when I configured to run my scripts on Jenkins, scripts are getting failed as chrome browser is not getting maximized.  However when I manually logged in to Jenkins node and execute my scripts, chrome browser is getting maximized. Any one come across solution for this issue? Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem similar to this when using Jenkins to run automated tests. It was to do with the interactive service detection.

The only way I could seem to fix this was to remove Jenkins as a windows service, and have it run from the CMD using a sciprt.

Comment: Yea i believe , i need to do it same way.

Comment: If this helps Rahul , be sure to mark it as an answer if it solves your problem so other people can be made aware. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same on [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) since it runs again as Windows service (on a virtual Desktop). After playing around with Firefox profiles, we had to use Full screen mode. Example code bellow (C#):

```
//Make Firefox fullscreen for TeamCity agent's runs
_driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript(
"window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height)");
_driver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(0, 0);
_driver.Manage().Window.Size = 
    new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.F11);
_driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("about:blank");
```

Chrome also support [such workaround](https://superuser.com/questions/643349/how-to-get-full-screen-in-chrome).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, still am not able to get the full size , do i need to copy all the code you gave ? or only the senkeys statement ?   And can you please give the code in Java ? it would be really helpful as am not able to find Position method from the above statements you gave.

Comment: This is the full solution that worked for me (should be pretty much language agnostic). But you can use just the JavaScriptExecutor part (also supported by JAVA) and the `_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.F11);` as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268617/sendkeys-in-selenium-web-driver). This should do the trick.

Comment: Used this,  still when i take the screen shot its same as before :( System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Used path for chrome driver");
  driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
  driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);

Comment: Even this dint work        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height)");
  driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
  
  
  driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1500,1800));
 driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
  Thread.sleep(4000);

Comment: Even this dint work , huh .. :( driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height)");  driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
  driver.manage().window().setSize(new(Dimension(1500,1800));
 driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
  Thread.sleep(4000);