# RemoteWebDriver - changing window size

Tags: selenium

I'm writing selenium tests. I have problem with one script because selenium can't find a element. I think that is a problem with RemoteWebDriver because when I'm watching screens I see that screen is incomplete, without right side with that button. If I'm using local driver I have line `driver.manage().window().maximize()` and that works. So my question is, is that possible to maximize size of RemoteWebDriver window? Maybe there is a alternative to get full screen in that Driver? I'm using Jenkins with selenium.

Comment: Look at this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715927/unable-to-maximize-browser-when-running-through-jenkins-as-windows-service

Comment: Okay, I find that: `The only way I could seem to fix this was to remove Jenkins as a windows service, and have it run from the CMD using a sciprt.` but could you tell me what is `remove Jenkins as a windows service`?

Comment: try this instead of maximixe
`// make window big
  firefoxDriver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0,0));
  firefoxDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1800,1100));`

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in chrome many times, and the workaround for me is to use javascript's [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to move the viewport to that element.

In php / phpunit-selenium:

```
$this->execute([
    'script' => 'var elm = document.getElementById("id");elm.scrollIntoView(true);',
    'args'   => $args
]);
// Continue to access element
```

You should be able to extract that bit within 'script' and execute it as raw javascript from within whatever language you use for your selenium tests.

Answer (score 0):

for chrome we can use

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

firefox doesnt need any `driver.window().manage().maximize()` in the latest geckodriver version